# Как получить два последних символа строки?

Tags: c++

Пример строки (std::string): 19 29 0. Нужно получить 0 и пробел перед ним.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::string c ("blablabla");
std::cout << c.[c.length - 1]; // возьмем длину строки и выведем последний символ 
std::cout << c.last; // вывести последний символ
```

Можно использовать итераторы. Например, [string::rend](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/rend/) для прохода по строке в обратном порядке. Тогда выводите первые два элемента, если они есть, и на выход.

Comment: +1, но почему не просто [substr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr)?

Comment: Даешь велосипеды в массы! А если серьезно, то автор вопроса не уточнил, в каком виде ему нужны два последних символа.

Comment: @gecube, IMHO неплохо бы проверить, **а есть ли в строке эти последних символа?**

Получаем что-то вроде:

     string s = ...;
     ...
     int i2 = s.length() - 2;
     string s2 = s.substr(i2 > 0 ? i2 : 0);
     
     cout << '[' << s2 << "]\n";